# Como criar uma mascara de senha em C

Tags: c, login, senhas, password

Criei este código em C para gerar mascara na senha, porém ele não deixa apagar os caracteres depois e nem salva a variável corretamente. O que pode ser ?

Segue código atual:

```
void login(){   


 int i,tam;
 char usuario[80], senha[80];
 printf("Digite o usuario. -> ");
 scanf("%s", usuario);
 printf("Digite a senha. -> ");
 fflush(stdin);
  for (i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
    senha[i] = getch();
    putchar('*');

}
printf("\n");
senha[i]='\0';    
scanf("%s", senha); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abaixo seu exemplo modificado:
inclua no seu projeto a biblioteca de strings string.h para o uso do memset.
É uma boa pratica zerar as variáveis na inicialização.

```
 int tam = 0;
 char usuario[80], senha[80], senha2[80];
 memset(usuario, 0x00, sizeof(usuario));
 memset(senha, 0x00, sizeof(senha));
 memset(senha2, 0x00, sizeof(senha2));

 printf("Digite o usuario. -> ");
 scanf("%s", &usuario);
 printf("Digite a senha. -> ");
 fflush(stdin);

    do
    {   
         senha[tam] = getch();          
         if(senha[tam] == 0x08 && tam > 0)  //Backspace
         {   
            printf("\b \b"); 
            senha[tam] = 0x00;
            tam--;

         } 
         else if (senha[tam] == 13) // Enter
         {  
            senha[tam] = 0x00;
            break;
        }
        else if (senha[tam] != 0x08)
        {
            putchar('*');
            tam++;              
         }
    }while(tam < 10) ;

printf("\nDigite a senha novamente ->");

scanf("%s", &senha2); 

if (strcmp(senha, senha2) == 0)
{
    printf("%s, Senha ok\n", usuario);
}
else 
    printf("%s, Senha invalida\n", usuario);
```

Comment: Estou tentando adaptar o código mas ele esta pedindo duas vezes a senha e na segunda vez sem mascara . Preciso que ele peça somente uma vez a senha e armazene na variavel "senha" seguindo para um "for" que utilizo para validar um txt com login e senha do que ja tenho cadastrado.

Comment: Retire o scanf("%s", &senha2) e a condição de comparação abaixo if(strcmp...  O que foi feito foi somente um validador, mas você pode retirar sem problemas que a senha ficará armazenada na variável "senha'. Sugiro que crie uma função separada do main para ser utilizada quando necessário o usuário digitar a senha, assim você pode reaproveitar o código.

Comment: Deu Certo ! obrigado #

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazendo um programinha para Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
  int i,tam;
  char usuario[80], senha[80];

  struct termios new, old;

  printf("Digite o usuario. -> ");
  scanf("%s", usuario);
  printf("Digite a senha. -> ");

  // salvando atual terminal
  tcgetattr (fileno (stdin), &old);
  new = old;
  new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // desligando o ECHO

  // setando novo terminal
  tcsetattr (fileno (stdin), TCSAFLUSH, &new);

  scanf("%s", senha);

  // setando para o antigo terminal
  (void) tcsetattr (fileno (stdin), TCSAFLUSH, &old);
}
```

Aqui segue a definição do `struct termios`:

```
struct termios
{
  tcflag_t c_iflag;      /* input modes */
  tcflag_t c_oflag;      /* output modes */
  tcflag_t c_cflag;      /* control modes */
  tcflag_t c_lflag;      /* local modes */
  cc_t     c_cc[NCCS];   /* special characters */
}
```

A função `tcgetattr` recupera as informações do terminal. Já, a função `tcsetattr` seta alterações, podendo passar algumas opções. A opção `TCSAFLUSH` diz que se houver alguns bytes a ler, será descartados.

Referências:

1. [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856689/3810242) no SO;
2. man do comando tcsetattr.

PS: não sei se roda em Windows.